# Sefer השולחן הטהור translated into Hebrew or English please?

Tags: product-recommendation, translation, yiddish

Is there a translation from the Yiddish to Hebrew or English of the 19-page Sefer [השולחן הטהור](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36541&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=)
by אברהם דוד ליפשיץ?

Comment: Seems like he wrote a bunch of short Kuntreisim on various topics all in yiddish

Comment: If there aren't any existing translations, there are plenty of translators you could hire (my guess: a couple hundred dollars).